# Conversion date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a big procedure which consists mostly dynamic SQL. I am having issues with setting one of the date fields.

```
DECLARE @WorkDate DATETIME 

SET @WorkDate = 'SELECT MIN(__Insert_Date) FROM  ' + @DatabaseName + '.'
                            + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '_Hist'

SET @WorkDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', @WorkDate), '19000101')
```

This is part of a big procedure. So when I execute the above query I am getting this error:

> *Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 68
>
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WorkDate is DATETIME and your setting it at as a sting thats why the conversion is failing
EDIT :

Try this:

```
DECLARE @WorkDate DATETIME, @WorkDateString varchar(100)

SET @WorkDateString = 'SELECT MIN(__Insert_Date) FROM  ' + @DatabaseName + '.'
                        + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '_Hist'

SET @WorkDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', @WorkDate), '19000101')
```

If you need to insert the `@WorkDate` into the select string where `__Insert_Date` is then you need to reverse the order to look like this

```
DECLARE @WorkDate DATETIME, @WorkDateString varchar(100)

SET @WorkDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', @WorkDate), '19000101')

SET @WorkDateString = 'SELECT MIN(' + CAST(@WorkDate as varchar(19)) + ') FROM  ' + @DatabaseName + '.'
                        + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '_Hist'
```

Don't know if you looking to insert the `@WorkDate` into the select string but that's how you could accomplish that

Comment: Even if you change @WorkDate to String it's giving the same Error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the date field in this database is not stored as a `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `19000101`, use `1900-01-01`.  It is unable to recognize your date formate for your character string or your `@WorkDate` value is not valid.

Comment: What is the output of `@WorkDate`?